# ASP.NET routing in WebForms does not handle non-ASP extensions when running under ASP.NET Development Server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-routing

I've created a default WebSite under Visual Studio 2010.
Added a simple routing there into Global.asax:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("AboutRoute", "about", "~/About.aspx");
```

This shows 404 when I start **ASP.NET Development Server** and browse to "http://localhost:6521/WebSite1/about"

But works nicely when I change `about` to `about.axd` (notice the .axd extension) and browse to /WebSite1/about.axd

What do I need to change in web.config to make Development Server work as IIS does (correctly handles extension-less URLs)?

Comment: Two things to try first of all; 1) In your project properties (right click the website project node in the solution explorer and choose properties), change the Virtual Path to be / rather than /WebSite1. 2) Change your url pattern match to about/ rather than just about. The ASP.Net Dev server should handle all URL's by default, unlike IIS which only routes requests for .aspx and the like to the ASP.Net runtime.

Comment: Why this should be changed if about.axd works nicely. For some reason Development Server doesn't handle extensionless URLs in this case.

Comment: Wanted to test to see if the dev server was having issues with a subfolder; a URL rewriting library we use had similar issues. The second is just about testing a more specific pattern.

Answer (score 0):

> This shows 404 when I start ASP.NET Development Server and browse to
>   "http://localhost:6521/WebSite1/about"

I prepared a sample Web Application, which gave me About us and Default.aspx pages.
In default.aspx page, I wrote the following code....

### Default.aspx.cs Code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect(Page.GetRouteUrl("AboutRoute", 
                        new { ID = "Evgenyt" }));
}
```

---

### Global.asax.cs Code

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    private void RegisterRoute(RouteCollection Routes)
    {
        Routes.MapPageRoute("AboutRoute", "about/{ID}", "~/About.aspx");

    }

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoute(RouteTable.Routes);
        // Code that runs on application startup

    }
}
```

---

Then I published the code and configured it on IIS. Now When the Request Reaches IIS, It routed the message to the aspnet_isapi.dll ISAPI extension. ISAPI extension then loaded the default.aspx page, execute it, and return its rendered HTML to IIS, and finally IIS then sends it back to the client.

### Resultant URL

http://localhost/Demo/about/Evgenyt

### Actual URL

http://localhost/Demo/AboutUs.aspx

---

> What do I need to change in web.config to make Development Server work
>   as IIS does (correctly handles extension-less URLs)?

[**Reference**](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=2wg5LCKuChcC&pg=PA773&lpg=PA773&dq=Routes.MapPageRoute%20implementation%20web.config&source=bl&ots=Hjv6eHvdLG&sig=8w10ierA20ixGRaAWyFeij4lLBk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vrtPT-LNGYnOrQen64XnDQ&sqi=2&ved=0CGAQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=Routes.MapPageRoute%20implementation%20web.config&f=false) - Unlike `URLMapping`, URLRouting does not take place in Web.config. It can be implemented using code. You can use Application_Start Event as mentioned in your code in Glogal.asax.cs file to register all routes for your application. To register a route you can use `RouteTable` class in `System.Web.Routing` namespace.

Comment: There is no problem with this on IIS (including express). But ASP.NET Dev Server doesn't handle non-ASP extensions for some reason.

Comment: take a look at this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx please read a topic named "What Happens When a Request Reaches IIS"

Comment: I do not need IIS. It works perfectly under IIS. It doesn't work under ASP.NET Development Server.

Comment: u mean when you are in debug mode?