# how to use regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, urlrewriter.net

I am using `UrlRewriter.NET` for `urlrewriting`...how do i write the regular expression for

`http://localhost:2731/CitiZenJourNalism/ViewProfile.aspx?uid=3eb5bf69-1047-4936-9885-8ff41d45646f`

in this format `<rewrite url = "~/ViewProfile/([^/.]+)" to="~/ViewProfile.aspx?uid=$1" />`

what should be the `rewrite url` for `http://localhost:2731/CitiZenJourNalism/Reports.aspx?cat=local&id=6`

Any help is appretiated.Thanks.

**EDIT:** Rewrite code in web.config file

```
 <configuration> 
<configSections> 
<section name="rewriter" requirePermission="false" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandle‌​r, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" /> 

</configSections> 

<system.web> 

<httpModules> 

<add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/> 

</httpModules> 

</system.web>


 <rewriter>

    <rewrite url="~/Reports/(.+)/(.+)" to="~/Reports.aspx?cat=$1&amp;id=$2" />


  </rewriter>
```

Comment: where does `cat=local&id=6` come from?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<rewrite url="~/Reports/(.+)/(.+)" to="~/Reports.aspx?cat=$1&amp;id=$2" />
```

Comment: when i run the page i get this error `Must declare the scalar variable "@ReportID"` the page is working fine without rewriting.

Comment: `http://localhost:2731/CitiZenJourNalism/Reports.aspx?cat=local&id=6` this is the original url

Comment: hey...its working fine ...i had an extra .aspx ...sorry..but when i am redirected to the page and i click on the home link i get this error `"Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Index.aspx' to data type int."`

Comment: i think now the issue is in the index.aspx

Comment: @user1150440 can you copy paste url where you'r getting this erro `Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Index.aspx' to data type int.` Your routing setting is redirecting index to another url.

Comment: i have not changed anything in the index page...and pls tell me what shud be the rewrite url for `http://localhost:2731/CitiZenJourNalism/ViewProfile.aspx?uid=3eb5bf69-1047-4936-9885-8ff41d45646f`

Comment: Will you like to explain something here....http://stackoverflow.com/a/9522264/1209450 ? I have done till without Querystring using Routing and need to understand it with querystring also using routing.

Comment: @rs you are right i am redirected to `http://localhost:2731/CitiZenJourNalism/Reports/local/Index.aspx` where as i should be redirected to `http://localhost:2731/CitiZenJourNalism/Index.aspx`

Comment: can you post all your routing settings?

Comment: `<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="rewriter"  
             requirePermission="false" 
             type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandler, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" />
  </configSections>
  
  <system.web>
      
    <httpModules>
      <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/>
    </httpModules>
    
  </system.web>
`

Comment: `<rewriter>
    
    <rewrite url="~/Reports/(.+)/(.+)" to="~/Reports.aspx?cat=$1&amp;id=$2" />


  </rewriter>`

Comment: can you hover on your Home link and see what url it displays? And please add code to main question not in comments.

Comment: when i hover it shows `http://localhost:2731/CitiZenJourNalism/Reports/local/Index.aspx`  but the real url is `http://localhost:2731/CitiZenJourNalism/Index.aspx`  i have added the code in the question

Comment: i am using a menu control...and the navigate url is `~/Index.aspx`

Comment: pages in which i have not used rewriting shows the correct url on hovering..but pages with url rewriting shows the wrong url on hovering...why?