# Index.aspx in a hybrid ASP.NET / ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a hybrid asp.net and asp.net mvc3 application.  It was originally just ASP.NET.  The default page is still in ASP.NET and when a user goes to http://mysite.com/ I want the index.aspx to come up.  Of course, the `routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" })` line in my global.asax ir rerouting tht to my MVC pages.

I tried the following but neither of them worked:

```
routes.MapRoute("DefaultPage", "/", "~/Index.aspx");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathinfo}");
```

Does anybody know what I should be doing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9522264/1209450

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To map the root to Index.aspx you need to use MapPageRoute, rather than MapRoute, as follows:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("DefaultPage", "", "~/Index.aspx"); 
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathinfo}");
```

Also ensure these lines are placed prior to the default route mapping.