# How to set an .aspx page as MVC default page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms

Got a project with standard Asp.Net (aspx) pages running alongside MVC 3 Razor controllers/views. Want to set the aspx page as the default page. As at the moment it's picking up the following route when opening the root

```
routes.MapRoute(
"MVCDefault", // Route name
"{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

(its now hosted in IIS7 it worked fine runnning in visual studio).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see here: [Index.aspx in a hybrid ASP.NET / ASP.NET MVC application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727669/index-aspx-in-a-hybrid-asp-net-asp-net-mvc-application)

```
routes.MapPageRoute("DefaultPage", "", "~/Index.aspx"); 
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathinfo}");
```

Comment: I actually just found a solution using a custom route handler and using routes.add, but your solution looks to be more eloquent.

Comment: And place those lines _before_ the other MapRoutes.